# Case Roll-up Field [Count]

Tags: trigger, roll-up-summary

I am trying to set up a trigger that updates a field that keeps the count of the related cases. But since it is my 1st trigger I am having a hard time to get it work. I googled some examples and tried to mimic the most similar one. Since I havent understood completely how to code a trigger, I cant go forward anymore.

This is what I got and hope you can help:

```
{
  //Objective: count the number of related cases through the Standard Field Parent (lookup)
  //Everytime a case is inserted, updated or delete, this trigger should update the field Number_of_Related_Cases__c 
  //with a count. 

  //Define the trigger and fire it up on insert and update    
  trigger Count_Related_Cases on Case (after insert, after update, after delete) {

  //Create a list named "rc" that will contain Case Records
  //Create a variable named "casid" that will hold the Parent ID
  //Store on caseid the Parent ID for the first case on the list rc     
  Case [] rc = Trigger.new; 
  ID caseid = null;
  caseid = rc[0].Parent;

  //Create a variable that will hold the count of cases that have the same Parent Case ID            
  Integer i = [select count() from Case where Parent = :caseid]; 

  //Create a list "s" that will have all the "Master Cases" that have at least one related Case.     
  Case [] s =[select id,Number_of_Related_Cases__c from Case where id = :caseid];

  //Update the Master Case field Number_of_Related_Cases__c with the count "i"    
  s[0].Number_of_Related_Cases__c = i;         

  // write to database    
  update s[0];     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it like this - that way it will be bulkified, and handle cases having their parent removed:

```
trigger Count_Related_Cases on Case (after insert, after update, after delete) {

//build list of parent case ids
    Set<Id> ParentIds = new Set<Id>();

  //If insert or update, use trigger.new
  if (trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate) {

  //if case has parent, add to set of parentids
  for (Case c: Trigger.New) {

      if(c.ParentId != null) {
      ParentIds.add(c.ParentId);
      }

  //if case previously had parent, but no longer does, also add so we can recalc
  if (trigger.isupdate) {

      if (trigger.oldmap.get(c.id).parentid != null && c.ParentId == null) {
      ParentIds.add(trigger.oldmap.get(c.id).parentid);
      }

     } 

  }
  }

  //if delete, make sure we update parent
  else if (trigger.isdelete) {

  for (Case c: Trigger.Old) {

      if(c.ParentId != null) {
      ParentIds.add(c.ParentId);
      }

  }
  }

  //then query for parent cases, and do inner query for related cases
    List<Case> pcount = [Select Id, (Select Id from Cases) From CASE where Id IN :ParentIds];

              //use size of inner cases to set number count
              for (Case pc: pcount) {
              pc.Number_of_Related_Cases__c = pc.cases.size();
              }
     //update parents         
    update pcount;
}
```

Comment: Is there something else that needs to be done to launch this trigger. I'm not familiar with triggers and need to know how to move this from the sandbox to production.

Comment: @Rachel - you will need to write a unit test, but that's a whole other question!

Answer (score 0):

This does the job and copes with reparenting as well as parent deletion. I don't test for null parent ids but I guess you could remove null from the set of ids prior to the Select but I don't find it a problem.

```
trigger CaseRollup on Case (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    Set<Id> parentList = new Set<Id>();

    if (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isInsert) {
        for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
            parentList.add(c.ParentId);
        }
    }
    if (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isDelete) {
        for (Case c : Trigger.old) {
            parentList.add(c.ParentId);
        }
    } 

    List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Cases) FROM Case WHERE Id IN :parentList];

    for (Case c : cases) {
        c.Case_Count__c = c.Cases.size();
    }

    update cases;   
}
```